# R rgdal shapefile to google-map like projection

Tags: r, projection, rgdal

I've been searching for a while to no avail, please help. I'm able to draw a simple world map using a shapefile (and do a lot more, draw lines, fill with colors, etc).

The source of shapefile is:

http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php

This is a simple example:

```
library(rgdal)
world <- readOGR("Z:/data/borders","TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3")
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(world)
```

[image]

However, the shape is quite different to what google map looks like. I suspect that it has something to do with projection, and I've been trying to adjust it but to no avail. So what I would like to do is to get my map to match the outlines of google projection (not the other way around).

The reason I need it is because I have a raster image layer that is based on google maps projection that I need to overlay on top of my map.

Your help would be really appreciated,

many thanks,

Alex

Comment: Google Maps uses [Web Mercator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator), FWIW.

Comment: and use `?spTransform` to transform the projection of a spatial object

Comment: If you "suspect that it has something to do with projection", I'd suggest you to read a primer on map projections and spatial reference systems before trying anything, so that you can have a grasp on what you are doing.